# How to Print my document with JsPdf and Html2Canvas in Nuxt Project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jspdf, html2canvas

Nuxtjs project.

```
   printPDF() {

            // Initialize the PDF.
            let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'in', [8.5, 11], false);
            let totalPage=0 

            this.userInfos.forEach((r, i) => {
//userInfos is to get user count
                const contentPrint = document.getElementById('contentPrint-' + i);

                html2canvas(contentPrint, {
                    scale: 2, useCORS: true, allowTaint: true, scrollY: 0
                })
                    .then((canvas) => {

                        const image = {type: 'jpeg', quality: 1};
                        const margin = [0.5, 0.5];
                        const filename = 'e-ticket';


                        let imgWidth = 8.5;
                        let pageHeight = 11;

                        let innerPageWidth = imgWidth - margin[0] * 2;
                        let innerPageHeight = pageHeight - margin[1] * 2;

                        // Calculate the number of pages.
                        let pxFullHeight = canvas.height;
                        let pxPageHeight = Math.floor(canvas.width * (pageHeight / imgWidth));
                        let nPages = Math.ceil(pxFullHeight / pxPageHeight);
                        totalPage+=nPages

                        console.log("nPages", nPages)
                        // Define pageHeight separately so it can be trimmed on the final page.
                        pageHeight = innerPageHeight;

                        // Create a one-page canvas to split up the full image.
                        let pageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        let pageCtx = pageCanvas.getContext('2d');
                        pageCanvas.width = canvas.width;
                        pageCanvas.height = pxPageHeight;


                        for (let page = 0; page <= nPages; page++) {
                            // Trim the final page to reduce file size.
                            if (page === nPages - 1 && pxFullHeight % pxPageHeight !== 0) {
                                pageCanvas.height = pxFullHeight % pxPageHeight;
                                pageHeight = (pageCanvas.height * innerPageWidth) / pageCanvas.width;
                            }

                            // Display the page.
                            let w = pageCanvas.width;
                            let h = pageCanvas.height;
                            pageCtx.fillStyle = 'white';
                            pageCtx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
                            pageCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, page * pxPageHeight, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);

                            // Add the page to the PDF.
                            if (page > 0) pdf.addPage();
                            // console.log("pdf",page)

                            let imgData = pageCanvas.toDataURL('image/' + image.type, image.quality);
                            pdf.addImage(imgData, image.type, margin[1], margin[0], innerPageWidth, pageHeight);

                        }

                    });


            });
           
            setTimeout(() => {

                pdf.deletePage(totalPage+1) //delete last empty page
                window.print()

                pdf.save("filename" + '.pdf')
            }, 3000)
        },
```

In my project, I have 2 buttons. The first is to create Pdf, the second button is to print documents. Many user's information can be seen on my web page separately and when I wanted I can print them separately.  This code area is to print pdf and it splits pages also. For example, if there 2 users and the first user's info can fill in 1.5 pages and the second user's info can fill in 3.2 pages, it fills these areas separately and shows them separately.

I want to do the same logic with Print also. When the user clicked Print I want to show user information separately, one under the other, and print them separately.

But here I cant separate pages when I wanted to print them. For example, all pages are a total of 6 pages but when I wanted to print it shows 4 pages because it fills empty places also.